# Retrofit conversion exception after http redirect

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit 1.9 with Gson to connect to my web api. Things were great until recently I accidentally stumbled across a problem.

I have a Wifi Router + Modem that automatically redirects http requests to its login page when it couldn't connect to the ISP. During one such scenario I tried to debug my app and started seeing Retrofit Conversion errors (`Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING` errors). Upon closer inspection I understood that Gson is actually trying to deserialize the entire login page of my wifi router due to the url redirection.

Is there anyway I could detect this redirection with retrofit and treat the error as Network error and not Conversion error?

Comment: Please state reason for downvotes so I can edit the question to be more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I now understand that Retrofit is a REST abstraction library so it has nothing to do with HTTP redirection. The problem needs to be solved on the HTTP client which retrofit uses. I am using OkHttpClient, so I had to disable redirects by calling `setFollowRedirects(false)` on the instance. If using HttpUrlConnection, one could call the static `setFollowRedirects(false)` and `setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)` on the instance. Hope it helps someone!